# Why is JSON coming from a server enclosed with Parenthesis?

Tags: json, parsing

I am requesting a URL from a server which returns a JSON response, and it is enclosed with parenthesis ().  I couldn't use a JSON parser because it is not a valid JSON:

Example:

```
({"responseHeader":{"status":0,"msg":"failure"}})
```

Strings enclosed with `()`are not a valid JSON.  Is this the problem with server response or do I need to do something special to avoid this?

I tried with POSTMAN Desktop app, it returns correct json on Pretty format by trimming parenthesis but in raw format, it is enclosed with ().

Comment: You could remove the first and last parenthesis would make it valid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include the following header in your request:

```
Accept: application/json
```

If that does not work or you already have it, there is really not much left for you to do. (There could be something special about the server application that is non-standard, but that's hard to guess.)

In the worst case, just trim ( and ) (trim only applies to the beginning and end of the string, so there is no worry of deleting any valid () in the middle):

```
[foo stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: 
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]
];
```

Comment: I tried with Accept type. It's not working. i think trimming is the only way(worst way) to handle this.